# how to listen to screen position with Next js?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

i try to listen to the scroll of page to do manipulation on my navBar ,
**what i want to do**: if the window is scroll, set opaciy 0.5 to the nav.
i mean -> if the header y !==0 so opacity to 0.5 for the nav.

i know that in plain js I can do something like window.scroll(y-coord) to get the actual position each time that he scrolled. but how can i implement it with Next js?
(i shortcut the code for better understand.

```
//////////////////style///////////
  const NavHeader = styled.header`
  background-color: transparent;
  height: 60px;
  opacity:1;`;

        <NavHeader>
            <MainNav>
        <p>something to render inside the Navbar
            </MainNav>
        </NavHeader>
```

i tried something like :

```
    useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener("scroll", window.scrollY);
     }, []);
```

but didnt work...

Comment: не совсем понятно зачем вы переправляете обработчик на числовое значение, ответ дан ниже.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked everything works, you need to remember to unsubscribe from events. And at the same time see if there are any errors in the console.

```
import Head from 'next/head'
import {useEffect} from 'react'; // don't forget
```

...

```
  useEffect(()=>{
    const scroll = (event) => {
      console.log(window.scrollY)
    }
    window.addEventListener("scroll", scroll, false);
    return  () => window.removeEventListener("scroll", scroll, false);
  },[])
```

[image: скриншот]